# "Unable to resolve host “<insert URL here>” No address associated with hostname"

Tags: ios

I have Ios App and put my back end in hosting called arvixe my main problem that if connect my app to internet throw Vodafone Egypt it stop for running and give me this Error
Unable to resolve host “” No address associated with host name

Although my App work correctly if i open it from any Connection provider I have this problem with the same error in my Android version

after i called customer support of arvixe  they said that we didn't block any internet providers in Egypt
and Vodafone customer support said if my Sim card work correctly with fb ,inst ,or YouTube that meaning that no problem from my side

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions:
1. Change the end of your computer to be
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
2. If you are using mobile app, install the app from the play store with name DNS changer and use Google DNS; this will solve your issue.

Comment: You have two solution 
1. Change you DNS from network setting on your PC to be
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
2. If you are using mobile app , install app from play store with name DNS changer and use Google DNS , then your issue will solve

Comment: Am not sure why you repeated your answer as a comment